# How to automatically allow the execution of code action from HLS in emacs?

Tags: emacs, haskell-language-server

When I try to execute any kind of code actions from eglot connected to hls within emacs, I have to accept by hand the execution of the code action in the following popup:

[image: Emacs pops this up for each code action]

I find this behaviour to be particularly annoying.

**Is there any way to configure emacs so that code actions are accepted and applied by default?**

I am using haskell-language-server version `2.2.0.0` and emacs version `29.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable `eglot-confirm-server-initiated-edits`. For instance, using the following:

```lisp
(setopt eglot-confirm-server-initiated-edits nil)
```

Alternatively, you may find this user option in the *Customize UI*, by entering `M-x customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `<eglot>` <kbd>RET</kbd>. It is named (naturally) *Eglot Confirm Server Initiated Edits*.

This user option is mentioned in the *Eglot* documentation. Namely, see [`(info "(eglot) Eglot Variables")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eglot.html#index-eglot_002dconfirm_002dserver_002dinitiated_002dedits).